# regular expression to return specific pattern from a string

Tags: regex, oracle

I am a beginner to oracle regular expression. I have following string

```
'Critical fix ;,DI 2.2.1 new fixes , DI 2.2.2 maintenance plan , DI 3.2.1 new patch'
```

From above string I want to get output as below using regexp_substr.

```
DI 2.2.1,DI 2.2.2,DI 3.2.1
```

The string in question can have multiple occurrences (DI x.x.x) and using regular expression it should return a command separated string as described in the output. 
Please help

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: You can't "return a comma separated string" using regex in it self. That has to be done by the hosting language. The regex can describe a certain pattern that you want to identify, and have capture groups making it easier to extract identified sub-patterns. But you'll need some kind of execution environment to turn it in to the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
select regexp_replace(B, '(.*DI\s\S+)(,.*$)', '\1')
from
(
select regexp_replace(A, '(.*?)(DI\s\S+)', '\2,') B
from
(
select 'Critical fix ;,DI 2.2.1 new fixes , DI 2.2.2 maintenance plan , DI 3.2.1 new patch' A
from dual
)
)
```

First with the help of `regexp_replace(A, '(.*?)(DI\s\S+)', '\2,') B` we remove most of not `DI\s\S+` text and add commas after each of `DI...` block.

```
DI 2.2.1,DI 2.2.2,DI 3.2.1, new patch
```

Second with the help of `regexp_replace(B, '(.*DI\s\S+)(,.*$)', '\1')` we remove last extra-comma and trailing text.

```
DI 2.2.1,DI 2.2.2,DI 3.2.1
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, I have only one doubt at following line

Comment: Thank you, it works , I just want to know  how  the syntax (.*?)  is working at line  "select regexp_replace(A, '(.*?)(DI\s\S+)', '\2,') B"    , does that merely means the values other than (DI\s\S+) as (.*?)  indicates we are matching any character except NULL with 0 or more occurrences , can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: @MukulSharma We use lazy evaluation, that's what `?` is for. It means capture as *least* as possible before we meet `DI\s\S+` group. That's why in `AAA DI 1.2 BBB DI 3.4` text we have 2 matches. Each match has 2 groups, in first match we have `AAA ` and `DI 1.2` groups, and replace them with `DI 1.2,`. In second match we have `BBB ` and `DI 3.4` groups replaced with `DI 3.4,`. Without `?` we would have only 1 match having 2 groups - `AAA DI 1.2 BBB ` and `DI 3.4`.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter said, an example of what you have tried would be helpful. Well, this is what am able to get based on your question.

Use this pattern DI\s\S+

See demo here https://regex101.com/r/kO2cZ1/4.

For it to be able to detect all occurrences, make sure you make use of /m. It enables you match all occurrences that in the string.